# Magento 2.2.5 custom theme js errors

Tags: javascript, requirejs, magento-2.2.5, custom-theme

I created a custom child theme for luma and it works fine. But when I extend the layout for Magento_Theme I start getting all kinds of javascript errors which are random, sometimes they don't appear at all.

Below is my folder structure

[image]

The problem appears when I add the Magento_Theme folder.

Below is the content of default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="footer" template="html/footer.phtml">
                <block class="Gs\Core\Block\Mailchimp" name="mailchimp" template="Gs_Core::mailchimp/form.phtml" />
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

and default_head_blocks.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!--Bootstrap css-->
        <css src="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Below is a sample of the errors:

[image]

I have tried recompiling, clearing cache, forcing a static content deploy manually deleting the static folder and the generated folder with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. The mailchimp.phtml had js code that was causing require.js to break.

Answer (score 0):

From above code not sure what you did wrong but you can take the reference to create the custom theme from [here](https://github.com/hitesh-srtpl/magento226-default/tree/master/app/design/frontend/Srtpl/default)

After copy from reference code,

1) Paste into your app/design/frontend folder

2) Run this command **php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f** from root directory of magento

3) Go to the admin side Content -> Design -> Theme
check your newly installed theme there or not?

4) If you see your theme listed in theme tab then Go to Content -> Design -> Configuration -> Click Edit on first record -> click on  Applied Theme drop-down choose your new theme

5) save the configuration and go to frontend just refresh a page

6) if you see broken UI run this command **php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush**

7) if you still see broken UI follow **Step 2**

8) paste you required CSS/js in respected folders in the new theme

that's it let me know if you have any query

Comment: The problem was a script in one of the mailchimp templates.